# Find $f(x) \ $: $f'(x) = f(x)^2 + f^{-1}(x) + \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{e^{t}}{t} dt$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

$$f'(x) = f(x)^2 + f^{-1}(x) + \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{e^{t}}{t} dt$$

I suspect this question is a typo because differential equations typically require initial or boundary conditions or more information about the properties of the function $f(x)$. Without any other information it's not possible to find $f(x)$.

Am I right?

Comment: For x=0, the integral is undefined. So what is the intended domain?

Comment: (1) What's the source of that differential equation? (2) When one does not specify the initial or boundary conditions, one is looking for the *general* solution to the differential equation.

Comment: This is not an ODE due to the inverse of the unknown function. It connects values of $f$ in at least two distinct points.

Comment: What is $f^{-1}(x)$? Is that the inverse function or is that $\frac{1}{f(x)}$?

Comment: @Dominique inverse function